# usage of "empty" in Array()

Tags: vba, excel

```
aProducts(lRow) = Array("Id Product", "Value A", "Value B")

'To copy value A
aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, .Cells(aPos(2)).Value2, Empty)

'To copy value B
aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, Empty, .Cells(aPos(3)).Value2)
```

Hi guys,

I use this piece of code in a loop to copy some values and their ID, but anyway, now I'd like to understand the usage of "Empty" in this code in order to add more value.

I tried:

```
aProducts(lRow) = Array("Id Product", "Value A", "Value B", "Value C")

'To copy value A
aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, .Cells(aPos(2)).Value2, Empty)

'To copy value B
aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, Empty, .Cells(aPos(3)).Value2)

'To copy value C
aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, Empty, Empty, .Cells(aPos(4)).Value2)
```

"Execusiion error 9"

Thanks in advance and sorry for my approximate english :/

**EDIT 1**

you can get the file here : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DpGwPWsIfbWWlJRDAzZldYek0/view?usp=sharing

**EDIT 2**

Thanks to all of you, I just found that i've forgot to remove

```
ReDim Preserve aProducts(lRow)
```

Comment: Did the error only occur after you added "To copy value C"?

Comment: the first code works when I don't try to add my value C

Comment: Can you provide a download link for the workbook?  If not I'm going to have to see more code to determine the problem.

Comment: i'll edit, thank you for your time

Comment: It's a 1 hour meeting, can't post it before, sorry had no choice

Comment: updated with the link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the following:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim arr_var     As Variant

    arr_var = Array(Empty, Empty, 5)
    Stop
End Sub
```

Then run it. Click with mouse over `arr_var`, press Shift + F2 and you will see this:
"Leer" means "Empty" in German.
[image]

Comment: I'll try it after my meeting

Comment: By the way, why should I try this? What's the point of this piece of code?

Comment: Showing how `Empty` looks like in the array.

Comment: Essentially, `Empty` is the initial / default value for any new array. You could also just issue the `Stop` after `Dim arr_var(2)` and you'd see that you've got an array of three elements all of which are `Empty`. So, by using `Empty` you are "resetting" the array to it's initial emptiness.

Comment: Oh right, didn't see the screenshot on mobile version thank you again, I'll be back in an hour :/

Comment: Thanks to your help, i found my mistake: i forgot to delete `ReDim Preserve aProducts(lRow)` that I forgot between my B and C values. Thanks for your tips, and have a great day @Vityata ! ;)

Comment: Welcome :) Its almost night at my place :)

Comment: Also have a great "almost night" :)

Comment: Thanks, have a great day/night as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? It looks like you forgot to update the last one when you copied it.

```
aProducts(lRow) = Array("Id Product", "Value A", "Value B", "Value C")

'To copy value A
aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, .Cells(aPos(2)).Value2, Empty, Empty)

'To copy value B
aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, Empty, .Cells(aPos(3)).Value2, Empty)

'To copy value C
aProducts(lRow) = Array(.Cells(aPos(1)).Value2, Empty, Empty, .Cells(aPos(4)).Value2)
```

I also think you wanted to update `.Cells(aPos(4)).Value2)` to have a `4` instead of a `3`.

Comment: I tried it but forgot to change it and it did not work (first thing it tried xD), i'll edit

Comment: I'll post it after my meeting